# iTextSharp The document has no pages. when SetWidths on table?

Tags: itext

i have a code that creates a PDF with iTextSharp with a table but when i set the widths to that table it throws an exception that says that the document has no pages, why??

This is a part of my code:

```
using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(string.Format("{0}{1}_test.pdf", outputPath, id), FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();
                //If add this line the exception is the same
                //document.NewPage();

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
                table.TotalWidth = 500f;
                float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f, 80f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f };
                //if this line is commented (table.SetWidths), the PDF works fine.
                table.SetWidths(widths);

.....

}
```

Comment: can you provide more code so easy to understand.

Comment: i dont know what "more code" do you mean... this is all the code, the rest of the code after table.SetWidths is not reached and it's only table.AddCell code...

Comment: i have post answer check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used `PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);` means 9 columns of table.
and you are set widths 
like `float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f, 80f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f };` for `10` 'columns' so please change it.
and use `float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f, 80f, 50f, 50f, 50f};`

then its working.

use this,

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f, 80f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f };
```

Comment: OMG!!!! damn! sorry for the question, that was the problem! but... c'mon iTextSharp.. the error could be more specific LOL.

Comment: in last use `document.Add(table);` and `document.Close();`